# jQuery, auto scroll down with auto loaded content

Tags: jquery, scroll, autoscroll

I like to know if there is any good approach to scroll down a div that it's content is autoloaded.

As en example, get the facebook. When you try to invite your friends to some event then popup a dialog with your friends. Into that dialog there are not all of your friends loaded. Instead, each time you scroll down new friends are loaded until you find tha last one.

So the exact question is, is there a way to auto scroll the div until find the last friend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dnspinger/

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: What I like to do, is not to autoload content. I already know how to :). What I like to do is to autoscroll while the content autoloading until match the end

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387592/javascript-mechanism-to-autoscroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-growing-page, 

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html